# Как установить шрифты в wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Я натянул свою верстку на WordPress. Все работает отлично, за исключением шрифтов. Они у меня подключаются через файл fonts.css, а находятся соответственно в папе fonts. Пути все указаны так:

functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_style ('fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/fonts.css');
```

fonts.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Mak';
src: url('../fonts/Mak-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/Mak-Light.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: 300;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Шрифты в папе присутствуют.
Все находится в папке assets (а она соответственно в папке с темой)

Comment: Тема основная или дочерняя? Что в консоли браузера?

Comment: Тема основная. В консоли только ошибки о неверном пути до файла картинок и все.

Comment: Поправьте пути и все, все делаете верно, пути кривые, в консоли все написано же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный путь нужно задать относительно корня сайта. Соотвественно, он будет таким:

```
/wp-content/themes/[НАЗВАНИЕ_ТЕМЫ]/assets/fonts/Mak-Light.woff2
```

Comment: Относительный путь более гибкое решение

Comment: Так это и есть относительный путь – доменное имя не указано. При смене темы стили также изменятся. Переживать не о чем.

Comment: wp-content можно поменять в настройках или плагином. theme тоже можно изменить)

Comment: У человека решение более гибкое и ему нужно просто пару точек воткнуть в нужном месте)